# Callcontext.Getdata returns null after transitioning from managed to Native and then to managed code

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, integration-testing

I have a legacy managed (.net) application which calls into COM Code through interop and after a whille comes back again in managed code through COM callable wrappers. While doing so it does use System.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext to make data flow through execution path.

I need to write an integration test covering this path. For that I set the CallContext in Arrange part of the test. However as the execution transitions back in managed code I see that CallContext.GetData() returns NULL
I have also seen that the current thread id changes when code transitions to native/com code.

However if I explicitly set Test execution apartment mode MTA , then i dont see thread ids being changed despite the hops between managed and unmanaged code. and Context.GetData works as expected.

Can someone please explain why is such behavior exhibited (Especially around changes to thread and apartment model)

Comment: That's all pretty normal, COM automatically marshals calls from one thread to another when necessary.  The thread state matters a lot.  CallContext cannot work across unmanaged thread transitions.  Arbitrarily changing the thread to MTA does have a knack for exercising code the way it was never meant to be used, you'll easily end up with five nasty bugs instead of one.  Talk to the author of the COM code to get the best advice.

Comment: Thanks Hans... i m still unable to understand why changing apartment model to MTA enables the code to execute on same thread unlike whats observed when the same is STA..